# Sveltekit Typescript parse error when importing types

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I have this very simple component in a brand new Sveltekit project:

```js
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import type { Load } from '@sveltejs/kit';
    export const load: Load = ({ url }) => {
    const company = url.searchParams.get('company');
    return {
      props: {
        company
      }
    };
  }
   
  </script>
<script type="ts">
        export let company: string;

</script>

<h1>{company}</h1>
```

However, I always get an error at the import line:
[image: parse error]

This also happens when I run the app outside VSCode, so it's not just a problem with the IDE.

My package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "testapp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
        "build": "svelte-kit build",
        "package": "svelte-kit package",
        "preview": "svelte-kit preview",
        "prepare": "svelte-kit sync",
        "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check --plugin-search-dir=. . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write --plugin-search-dir=. ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^1.0.0-next.34",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.27.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.27.0",
        "eslint": "^8.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.7.1",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.6",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.2"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution: when changing the adpater, I accidently removed svelte preprocess from svelte.config.js. Doing it like this, and it works perfcetly fine:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I did the same thing because of the sveltekit documentation on the static adapter: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#usage

Comment: Ah thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware that it was missing in the documentation. I created a PR to change that: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/8811

Comment: While the PR was denied so the docs stay the same (for good reasons - if you use vanilla JS you don't need that for example) we might get a better error message in the future.