# SvelteKit doesn't seem to understand "import type"

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, sveltekit

I have this error when trying to use `import type` in Svelte. Everything is up to date, I tried to restart the svelte language server, IDE. Do I need to adjust svelte.config.js? I had the same problem with the new function from svelte called `snapshot`. What am I missing?

```
<script lang="ts">

    import type { ActionData } from './$types

    export let form: ActionData

</script>
```

error

[image]

svelte.config.js

[image]

vite.config.js

[image]

Comment: Is the [necessary preprocessor](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/preprocess.md) installed/configured?

Comment: I upgraded my answer, where is visible that I have "preprocess" in svelte.config.js included but the same error still occurs. But I didn't install anything maybe that's it. What should I install?

Comment: Do **not** screenshot code, insert it as text and format it. If that was setup with `npm create svelte...` to use TS, you should not need anything else.

Comment: You are missing the closing quote in `import type { ActionData } from './$types`... I was thinking that could be the problem but I get a different error if I try that

Comment: Thank you Odilf. I truly missed that closing quote. Unbelievable.

Comment: same quetion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846408/sveltekit-typescript-parse-error-when-importing-types

Answer (score 0):

adding lang="ts" attr to the script tag work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you must add preprocess to your svelte.config.js file

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';


/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
   preprocess: preprocess(),
   kit: {
    // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
    // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
    // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
    adapter: adapter()
}
};

export default config;
```